# Project Euler - Largest prime factor in Scala

Tags: scala, prime-factoring

I've been trying to solve project [Euler number in 3](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=3) in Scala, and this is what I've got so far:

```
def largestPrimeFactor(in:BigInt) : Option[BigInt] = {
  def isPrime(in:BigInt) : Boolean = {
    def innerIsPrime(in:BigInt, currentFactor:BigInt) : Boolean = {
        if(in % currentFactor == 0) {
        false
      }
      else {
        if(currentFactor > (in / 2)){
           true
        }
        else {
          innerIsPrime(in, currentFactor + 1)
        }
      }
    }

     innerIsPrime(in, 2)
  }

   def nextLargeFactor(in:BigInt, divisor:BigInt) : (Option[BigInt], BigInt) = {
     if((in / 2) > divisor) {
       if(in % divisor == 0) (Some(in / divisor), divisor) 
       else nextLargeFactor(in, divisor + 1)
     }
     else
       (None, divisor)
   }

   def innerLargePrime(in : BigInt, divisor:BigInt) : (Option[BigInt], BigInt) = {
     nextLargeFactor(in, divisor) match {
       case (Some(factor), div) => {
         if(isPrime(factor)) (Some(factor), div)
         else innerLargePrime(in, div + 1)
       }
       case (None, _) => (None, divisor)
     }
  }

  innerLargePrime(in, 2)._1
}
```

Which I think will work, but I'm stuck at work (making use of time during slow builds) and only have the SimplyScala service - which is timing out (I'll check it at home).

But as this is the first bit of Scala of any length I've written I'd thought I'd ask, what horrendous sins have I committed? How hopelessly suboptimal is my solution? What conventions have I trampled on?

Thanks!

Comment: That number is `Long`, which is much faster than `BigInt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't really get what you try to accomplish. It's that simple:

```
def largestPrimeFactor(b : BigInt) = {
  def loop(f:BigInt, n: BigInt): BigInt =
     if (f == n) n else 
     if (n % f == 0) loop(f, n / f) 
     else loop(f + 1, n)
  loop (BigInt(2), b)
}
```

Although there is nothing optimized here, I get the result instantly. The only "tricks" are that you have to know that the smallest factor (greater one) of a number is "automatically" prime, and that you can divide the number once you have found a factor.

Comment: I will plead lack of sleep, and mind-numbing work for my rubbish algorithm.

Comment: How is the execution time for either algorithm?

Comment: Just to add to something Landei said--sometimes optimizations do little more than add unnecessary complexity. This isn't to say that you shouldn't try to think about the problem in a way that will get the job done efficiently, but if you have a solution that gets the job done without a real performance problem, additional tweaking is just premature optimization (which, in the words of Don Knuth, is "the root of all evil.")

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/):

```
lazy val ps: Stream[Int] =
  2 #:: ps.map(i =>
    Stream.from(i + 1).find(j =>
      ps.takeWhile(k => k * k <= j).forall(j % _ > 0)
    ).get
)

val n = 600851475143L
val limit = math.sqrt(n)
val r = ps.view.takeWhile(_ < limit).filter(n % _ == 0).max
```

r is your answer